# Google maps mashup unexpected error

Tags: java, javascript

I am making a mashup between google maps and songkick, however i am running into an error that i dont understand.  The program connects via an applet to get a list of concerts and locations.  Then it passes that list as a string seperated by | to the javascript method test.  There it should create a LatLng object.  Here is my html file code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCYstt2SQVTX52XZ-hhvt1Smd9UZTTqDho&sensor=false">
</script>
<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850), zoom:5, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
}

function test(name, lat, lon)
{
var names = name.split("|");
var lats = name.split("|");
var lons = name.split("|");

for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++)
{
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i],lons[i]);
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:600px;"></div>

<applet code=GreendayConcerts.GreenDayConcerts.class 
        archive="Applet.jar"
        width=120 height=120>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my java code

```
public class GreenDayConcerts extends Applet
{
    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/269937/calendar.xml?apikey=lKK1RXr7dIu9fhIw");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(url.openStream());
            Element resultsPage = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("resultsPage").item(0);
            Element results = (Element) resultsPage.getElementsByTagName("results").item(0);
            NodeList events = results.getElementsByTagName("event");
            StringBuffer names = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer lats = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer lons = new StringBuffer();

            for(int i = 0; i<events.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element event = (Element) events.item(i);
                names.append("|"+event.getAttribute("displayName"));
                Element location = (Element) event.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0);
                lats.append("|"+Float.valueOf(location.getAttribute("lat")));
                lons.append("|"+Float.valueOf(location.getAttribute("lng")));
            }

            String name = names.toString();
            String lat = lats.toString();
            String lon = lons.toString();
            name = name.replaceFirst("[|]", "");
            lat = lat.replaceFirst("[|]", "");
            lon = lon.replaceFirst("[|]", "");
            JSObject.getWindow(this).call("test", new Object[]{name, lat, lon});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This line     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i],lons[i]); seems to be causing the problem

I am also a newbie at js but i am advanced in java.

Edit: The error i am getting is No such method "test" on JavaScript object.  However it appears to works fine when the for loop is removed.

Comment: Where do you use "var myLatlng". It's local to the for loop, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i had done

```
    for(int i = 0; i<events.getLength(); i++)
```

it should have been

```
for(var i = 0; i<events.getLength(); i++)
```